Program to find GCD of 2 numbers using euclids algorithm
#include?<stdio.h>
int gcd(int a, int b)
{
if(b==0) {
return a;
}
else {
return gcd(b, a%b) ;
}
}
int main() {
int num1, num2;
printf("enter 1st no:") ;
scanf (”%d”,&num1) ;
printf("enter 2nd no:") ;
scanf (”%d”,&num2) ;
printf ("GCD of %d and %d is: %d\n" ,num1, num2, gcd(num1, num2) ) ;
return 0;
}

your program contains the following faults that stops the version of gcc the is shipped with Ubuntu from compiling it:

include?<stdio.h> should not have a question mark in it.
in several places you have unicode quote characters instead of the ascii quote character. the gcc compiler does not accept unicode characters in source code.

normally it would be considered "bad form" to post corrected program source, but, in this case, since the errors were just character formatting there seems no harm   :-)
here is the fixed version of your program:
#include <stdio.h> 
int gcd(int a, int b) 
{ 
  if(b==0) { return a; } else { return gcd(b, a%b) ; }
}

int main() 
{ 
  int num1, num2; 
  printf("enter 1st no:") ; 
  scanf ("%d",&num1) ; 
  printf("enter 2nd no:") ; 
  scanf ("%d",&num2) ; 
  printf ("GCD of %d and %d is: %d\n" ,num1, num2, gcd(num1, num2) ) ; 
  return 0; 
}

and here is the result of compiling and running it:
user@user-DH61BE:~/Documents$ ls
GCD.c
user@user-DH61BE:~/Documents$ gcc GCD.c
user@user-DH61BE:~/Documents$ ls
a.out  GCD.c
user@user-DH61BE:~/Documents$ ./a.out
enter 1st no:20
enter 2nd no:25
GCD of 20 and 25 is: 5
user@user-DH61BE:~/Documents$ 

